# Android app and its service being killed after open some applications

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I'm developing an app to track the user location when they hit the button Start. I implemented a service to record the location with the LocationListener and it works well but I have being done some heavy testing and when I open some applications my app and service are getting killed by android randomly.

But I downloaded an app called Wikiloc and doing the same heavy test, opening multiple apps this app is never getting killed and I see the app creates a notification that can't be dismissable. Can it be related to the fact that the app is never killed by the system?

How can acheive this in my app? Do I have to do the notification trick? If so, how it is implemented?

Comment: do you try use [sticky mode](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) in your service?

Comment: @Alexander yes, my onStartCommand looks like this: `@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        runningService = true;
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the Android Service's `startForeground(int, Notification)` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)). According to the documentation:

> Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too much harm. You can set this flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as if your service is performing background music playback, so the user would notice if their music stopped playing.

You call `startForeground` inside your Service's `onCreate` method.

Comment: thanks for that, service is working now in foreground and it is not getting killed by Android doing some testing but, my activity is restarted, how I prevent that?

Comment: I don't think that you can stop that from happening (not 100% sure though). You can solve this by putting any state information in the Service (or in internal storage) and when the Activity is restarted you can get the data from the Service to populate the Activity. This will give the impression that the Activity never was destroyed.

Comment: Do you think SharedPreferences could be a good way to store the state of the service?

Comment: That is an option. Shared preferences do not handle arrays (lists, etc) of things well (the API is all primitive types: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). However, you could get around this by serializing your data into Json (a specially formatted string) and saving the state as a string that would be parsed when the activity is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, a little question, if the system kills the service, the onDestroy method of the service is called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110547/discussion-between-xmarston-and-curob).